# Adding pages to Drupals installation screen

Tags: drupal, configuration, drupal-7

After much googling I haven't been able to find a way to add additional
pages to the Drupal 7 installation screen. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/user-registration-module-for-drupal

Comment: @ceejayoz I think you've got the wrong link there, that one's about the User Registration Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_install_tasks()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7) in your profile. From the docs page:

> Any tasks you define here will be run, in order, after the installer has finished the site configuration step but before it has moved on to the final import of languages and the end of the installation.

Take the Commerce Kickstart profile as a good example:

```
function commerce_kickstart_install_tasks() {
  $tasks = array();

  // Add a page allowing the user to indicate they'd like to install demo content.
  $tasks['commerce_kickstart_example_store_form'] = array(
    'display_name' => st('Example store'),
    'type' => 'form',
  );

  return $tasks;
}

function commerce_kickstart_example_store_form() {
  // ...
}
```